# How can I redirect users to different pages?

Tags: reactjs, components, render

My components are not rendering as they should.
When save button is clicked my "add operation" component should post a form, dispatch it to the store, then show a success message and redirect the user to the home route ('/'). The problem is that the post action and the dispatch works fine but the success message and the redirect are not working

Here is the function:

```
...
const saveChanges = async () => {
        try{
            const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/operation', form);

            dispatch({
                type: 'ADD_OPERATION',
                operation: response.data
            });
            swal('YAY!', 'The operation was successfully added', 'success');

            props.history.push('/');
        }
...
```

Same thing is happening at my "edit" component:

```
...
    const editOperation = async () => {
        try{
            await axios.put('http://localhost:3000/operation/' + params.id, editForm);

            swal('YAY!', 'Operation edited', 'success');

            props.history.push('/operations/lists');
        }
...
```

Any idea what it could be?